# from text file to variables reading line by line

Tags: text, getline

I want to read a text file content line by line and assign to my variables. How can I do this ? I will write in **C** and there should not be the '\n' character.

Text file content:

```
9600
502
N
1
8
N
```

Variables

```
int     baudrate;
int     port;
char    parity;
char    databits;
char    stopbit;


while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    printf(line);
}
```

Comment: Specify a language for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Specify the path of the file from where you would get the file in the path variable.

string path = '' // File path which needs to be read. 
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

If the number of lines in the files is fixed and the variables in which you want the values to be saved remains the same it can be done as under : 

baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(readText[0]);
port = Convert.ToInt32(readText[1]);
parity = Convert.ToChar(readText[2]);
databits = Convert.ToChar(readText[3]);
stopbit= Convert.ToChar(readText[4]);
```